# Install Mobile Partner in Ubuntu 13.04 without download

Tags: installation, permissions, mobile-broadband

I have Huwawei E303 HSPA Dongal and it has already provided software for Linux.But I cant install it.

This is Dongal
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-fIdfg85yv1M/UdciqwwTdnI/AAAAAAAAAX0/Q7ObEgg4hkQ/s588-no/Screenshot+from+2013-07-06+01%253A06%253A08.png

I have very few knowledge about Ubuntu.I tried in terminal as fallowing.

```
root@nandika-OEM:~# su
root@nandika-OEM:/home/nandika# 
root@nandika-OEM:/home/nandika# /media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install
bash: /media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: Permission denied

root@nandika-OEM:/home/nandika# dash /media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install
/media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: 43: /media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: LANGUAGESTRING[0]=zh: not found

/media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: 44: /media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: LANGUAGESTRING[1]=en_US: not found

/media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: 45: /media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: LANGUAGECODE[0]=0: not found

/media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: 46: /media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: LANGUAGECODE[1]=1: not found

/media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: 49: /media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux/install: Bad substitution
```

root@nandika-OEM:/home/nandika#

Help to install.I cant get call,SMS without this.
But I Can connect internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect your 3G dongal & run the following codes in the Terminal one after another:

> cp -r /media/nandika/Mobitel/Linux ~/
>   cd ~/Linux
>   chmod +x install
>   sudo ./install

Answer (score 0):

First go to the folder and right click on the `mobilepartner.bin` file, then check run as executable from **Properties** -> **Permissions** -> **Allow executing file as program** menu.

Now, try the above command and if you are using 64bit system you may need to download 32bit libraries, by using `apt-get install` command.